# .Shift() first element from json callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem,
I made a call in ajax,
The result is callback in JSON.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/xxx.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(callback){
            if(callback.pstatus=='ok'){
                // do somthing
            }
            if(callback.pstatus=='bad'){
                callback.shift();
                self.showErrors(callback);
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to SHIFT() the element named "pstatus".
But i got an error at console "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'shift'".

Thanks.

Comment: `.shift` only works on Arrays.  You have a non-array object.  Try putting `console.log(callback)` in there, to see if the array is a property of the object.

Comment: And if i'll use Array.prototype.shift.apply() ?

Comment: It's not an array.  It'll add a length attribute to your object, but have no other effect.  What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the `pstatus` property you can just delete it.

```
delete callback.pstatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned as `callback` is an object, not an array. `Array.prototype.shift` will have no real effect. If you wanted to take the same action as `Array.prototype.shift`, you could just delete the first member of the `callback` object:

```
for(var k in callback) {
    delete callback[k];
    break;
}
```

Comment: And if i'll use Array.prototype.shift.apply() ?